# How setup Atommaper v 9.0 in MVC 5?

Tags: automapper, asp.net-mvc-5.2

In a previous project I worked with Automapper v7.0.1 and everything was fine.

Now I am working on a new project and again I made my architecture with MVC 5 and .Net framework 4.8, but I discovered that with the new version my configuration using PROFILE does not work correctly, I already tried some things on the web, but I cannot get it to work correctly.

Can you help me with the configuration and how to use the "PROFILE" in this new version?

Thank you..

Setup with V7.0.1

```
 public class AutoMapperConfiguration
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(x =>
            {                
                x.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile>();
                x.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappingProfile>();               
            });
        }        
    }
```

"PROFILE" 1

```
public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile()
        {

            CreateMap<ListAccountUsersViewModel, ApplicationUser>();
        }
    }
```

"PROFILE" 2

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public DomainToViewModelMappingProfile()
        {
            ConfigureMappings();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a mapping between source (Domain) and destination (ViewModel)
        /// </summary>
        private void ConfigureMappings()
        {
            CreateMap<ApplicationUser, ListAccountUsersViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

as I use it in the "Controller" and it works fine:

```
var listUserModel = accountUserService.GetUserList();

var mapperListUserModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>, IEnumerable<ListAccountUsersViewModel>>(listUserModel);
```

Now, configuration with v9.0

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
    {

        public static IMapper Mapper { get; private set; }

        public static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration { get; private set; }
        public static void Configure()
        {
            MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(x =>
            {                
                x.AddProfile(new ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile());
                x.AddProfile(new DomainToViewModelMappingProfile());
            });

            Mapper = MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
        }

    }
```

"PROFILE 1" and "PROFILE 2" they remain the same

as I use it in the Bootstrapper with Autofac:

```
 var assemblyNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
 var assembliesTypes = assemblyNames
                .Where(a => a.Name.Equals("Seccion.Web.Mappings", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .SelectMany(an => Assembly.Load(an).GetTypes())
                .Where(p => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsPublic && !p.IsAbstract)
                .Distinct();

 var autoMapperProfiles = assembliesTypes
                .Select(p => (Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(p)).ToList();

 builder.Register(ctx => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
 {
    foreach (var profile in autoMapperProfiles)
    {
      cfg.AddProfile(profile);
    }
 }));

 builder.Register(ctx => ctx.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper()).As<IMapper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

as I use it in the "Controller" and not working:

```
    private readonly MapperConfiguration config;
    //CTOR
    public AccountUserController(IAccountUserService  accountUserService, MapperConfiguration config)
    {
       this.accountUserService = accountUserService;
       this.config = config;
    }

    // ActionResult
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    var listUserModel = accountUserService.GetUserList();

//Here send Error: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
    var mapperListUserModel = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>, IEnumerable<ListAccountUsersViewModel>>(listUserModel);
```

**Can you help me with the configuration and how to use the "PROFILE" in this new version?**

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#examples

Comment: Mmmm but the documentation indicates for MVC CORE and I am using MVC 5, can this also be used for MVC 5?

Comment: Yes, and whatever DI you have, you can use it with AM. For many, people already did the integration.